# Most strange issue with Crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports-xi

This is very strange. I have a CR that takes over 30 minutes to run. It uses 5 large tables and queries the server. I made a View on the server which is IBM i to gather the data there. For some reason it is not giving me data on the CR past 08/12. When I query past that date on the server,it does have data, and even if I make a quick report on CR it will show all the data incl 2013.

The reason can possibly be this>

When I made the View, I mistakenly had a mix of databases used. And one of the 2 databases was one being used as part of a data purge. So it may have not had data past 8.12/

But since that point, I have also modified the View to add some new columns and this it does and even shows them in the data that it does show (till 8/12)

So this would tell me that the CR is fully using the new View.

So I can re create the CR but this is rather tedious. Perhaps there is one thing I am not doing?

Answer (score 0):

Crystal Reports generally does better in reporting over processing a query.  For a faster, and easier way of debugging, it's often better to make a procedure in your database that joins together the data from various sources.  Once you have the data you want, then use Crystal to display that data.

In other words, try to avoid doing any more work in Crystal than you have to.  Sure, the grouping and headers and pretty formatting will be done there.  But all of the querying, joining, and sorting is better done in your database.  If the query is slow there, then you can optimize there.  If the wrong data is returned, you fix your procedure until it is returning what you want.

An additional benefit is when the report needs to change.  If the data needs to come from a different location, you can modify the procedure and never touch Crystal.  If the formatting needs to change, you can modify the Crystal and never touch the procedure.  You're changing less and thus don't have to test everything.

Answer (score 0):

Is the crystal report attached to a scratch server?

If you are using SQL Server, then you can modify the SQL that constitutes your view by modifying the table names to be like this: *databasename..tablename* I'm not certain how to do the equivalent in other DBMS.

If you modify your table like that so that the view is querying tables from the correct non-purged database and you are still not getting data more recent than 8/12, then check if there are constraints in the WHERE and/or HAVING statements, or if there are implicit/explicit constraints in ON section of the JOINs.

Comment: I forgot one last thing, if you are working with a view, maybe the *view* is pointing toward an out of date table...